# Creating Rule for deleting untagged Instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to introduce new Rule for EC2 Instances.

1. Instances to be deleted without a Name tag
2. Instances to be stopped without `KEEP_RUNNING: TRUE` tag

Please give some idea to deliver the above.

Comment: What rule? Can you provide any examples of your code and those rules?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for considering Even I m not sure I need to  create rule in cloudwatch events and write logic to stop or terminate instances based on the tags Give me some example or idea to proceed with these

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Cloudwatch event and attach it to a lamda that will have your logic. I will provide you some functions in Javascript.

For fetching ec2 tags there is a function named [**describeTags**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeTags-property)

```
 /* This example describes the tags for the specified instance. */

 var params = {
  Filters: [
     {
    Name: "resource-id", 
    Values: [
       "i-1234567890abcdef8"
    ]
   }
  ]
 };
 ec2.describeTags(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    Tags: [
       {
      Key: "Stack", 
      ResourceId: "i-1234567890abcdef8", 
      ResourceType: "instance", 
      Value: "test"
     }, 
       {
      Key: "Name", 
      ResourceId: "i-1234567890abcdef8", 
      ResourceType: "instance", 
      Value: "Beta Server"
     }
    ]
   }
   */
 });
```

You can use this function to fetch the tags of an ec2 instance or multiple ec2 instances.

Then you can filter the ones you want to be deleted based on the tag Value and use the function **[stopInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#stopInstances-property)** or terminate them with **[terminateInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#terminateInstances-property)**.

```
/* This example stops the specified EC2 instance. */

 var params = {
  InstanceIds: [
     "i-1234567890abcdef0"
  ]
 };
 ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    StoppingInstances: [
       {
      CurrentState: {
       Code: 64, 
       Name: "stopping"
      }, 
      InstanceId: "i-1234567890abcdef0", 
      PreviousState: {
       Code: 16, 
       Name: "running"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
   */
 });
```